# jquery.flot IE8 Labels

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer-8, flot

I have some little problems with the jquery.flot plugin. When i test my graphs in IE 8, it seems like the font is automatically changed.

Screenshot from IE8
[image: Screenshot IE 8]

Screenshot from Chrome
[image: Screenshot Chrome]

Does anybody of you had same problems? I cant figure out where the problem is.

Thx for Help

Comment: What version of Flot are you using, and how are you specifying the font, exactly?

Comment: Iam using version 0.8 alpha. I dont set any special font declaration. But in my opinion the font-family in the IE8 screenshot isn a standard font. It looks like something special.

Comment: Try updating to 0.8.0-beta (latest master); it includes a number of text-related changes compared to earlier versions of the alpha.  Aside from that, are there any user-agent stylesheets in play?  If you try on a different machine, does the problem still come up?

Comment: Perfect! With the latest master the label font-family lokks great, even in IE8.

Answer (score 0):

(answer adapted from my comment)

Flot 0.8 alpha included a change to render text directly to canvas.  That was split off to a plugin shortly before the beta release, with the core functionality reverting to using HTML text, as it did in earlier versions of the library.

The font change would then appear to be a bug in Excanvas/Flashcanvas, depending on which you're using, where it's choosing the wrong font when rendering to canvas.  Once you upgraded to 0.8 beta text was once again left up to the browser, which did the right thing.